# Setting the circle radius in d3js with a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a set of data in searchButton function that calls different numbers in an array like so: `values[80,20,10]` Then in my x variable I have this scale for d3js.

```
x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(values)])
.range([0, width]);
```

Now I have a function called grow and within it I grow a set of circles based on the values in searchbutton function.

```
this.grow = grow;
function grow(size) {
  circle.attr("r",size / 5 + 10).transition().duration(2000);
}
```

when I set the grow function with size as the parameter it grows but transition is not working at all on it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a `d3` transition to work, you need to animate a property starting from a default value to the desired value. What would I do is following:

```
this.grow = grow;

function grow(size) {
     circle
           .attr('r', 0)
           .transition()
           .ease('linear')
           //.ease('cubic-in-out') // default
           .duration(2000)
           .attr('r', size / 5 + 10);
}
```

This will animate a circle from 0 radius to the desired radius. You may need to adjust your logic, maybe you don't want as default radius (before transition) a value of 0.

Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or post your entire code? How are you calling the `grow` function?

Comment: First off thanks for the quick reply, I appreciate it. I am calling the grow function in the searchButton(), like this ball1.grow(x(values[0])). 

So I would like it to grow when I hit that button.
Don't know much about fiddle but will find out.

Comment: How are you defining the circle variable? It would be really helpful if you could create an example on this [site](http://jsfiddle.net/). Something like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/).

Comment: All these functions are within a bigger function and the circle is defined as such

 var circle = svg.append("circle")
                                .attr("r", 13)
                             .style("fill", color)
                                .style("stroke", color)
13 is my starting radius.

Comment: I am going to try and do that, give me just a second.